# Adding setUTCDate() to replace "computers" time

Tags: javascript

I followed [this tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery/), but I wanted to just be able to set a date and have it countdown to that date.

Even so, it would just base it off my computer's time; how can I make it so it's standard for everyone?

He mentioned `setUTCDate()` but I have no idea how to implement it?

Comment: Get Server time with server-side language.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use the standard utc time? 
And I read somewhere "It's not possible with server-side to make a clock count-down" But I cant remember where. (which....would defeat the purpose of everything I'm trying to do lol)

Comment: No not the count-down with a server-side language just get the current date server-side and use it in JavaScript.

Comment: Could you find me a tutorial or something of the sort? I've been looking for about 20 minutes now and Can't find much of anything..
(still new to any type of scripting, slowly trying to learn bits and pieces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code to get you started. It gets the UTC time and `alert`'s it, formatted:

```
// By default, JS does not pad times with zeros
function checkTime(i) {
    if(i<10) i='0'+i;
    return i;
}

// Set current UTC time
var d = new Date();
var now = checkTime(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' +
    checkTime(d.getUTCMinutes()) + ':' +
    checkTime(d.getUTCSeconds());

// Output
alert(now);
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dcC3k/).

**Remember:** UTC != GMT (read on if you want this to always match the UK time).

---

BST (when the clocks go forward) will need to be factored in for anyone in the UK wanting to use this solution.

Here's a function I wrote earlier:

```
// Function returning 0 or 1 depending on whether BST is in effect
function isBSTinEffect()
{
    var d = new Date();

    // Loop over the 31 days of March for the current year
    for(var i=31; i>0; i--)
    {
        var tmp = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 2, i);
        if(tmp.getDay() == 0) { lSoM = tmp; break; }
    }

    // Loop over the 31 days of October for the current year
    for(var i=31; i>0; i--)
    {
        var tmp = new Date(d.getFullYear(), 9, i);
        if(tmp.getDay() == 0) { lSoO = tmp; break; }
    }

    if(d < lSoM || d > lSoO) return 0;
    else return 1;
}
```

To factor in BST, put that function before `// Set current UTC time` and change `checkTime(d.getUTCHours())` to `checkTime(d.getUTCHours()+isBSTinEffect())`